# Mapping KeyDown Event into a ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm trying to mapping the `KeyDown` event into my `ViewModel`.

But the event is never triggered.

Here is the XAML code:

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown" SourceName="this">
        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnViewKeyDown"                
            TargetObject="{Binding}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And here is the code of my `ViewModel`:

```
    public void OnViewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I've tried to map another events of the view, and they worked perfectly. The ones I tried works perfectly, only the `KeyDown` that doesn't work.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Would the event fire, if you would use it in your View? (just to make sure, the key down is fired)

Comment: Can you show all the code for your ViewModel?